# What's the meaning of the phrase "narrative arc"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The chapters that follow, trace a **narrative arc** through nine variations on the multiverse theme.

This is a sentence from a book about 9 different types of the parallel universes (multiverse). I'm wondering what is the meaning of the phrase "narrative arc" in here.

Comment: Google finds good descriptions of "narrative arc", try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is the word ***narrative***, which is normally a *noun*, is being used as an *adjective*, allowing the writer to introduce another noun ***arc*** which that adjective can modify. It's actually a fairly common term in Lit Crit, and [this is as good a definition as any...](http://contemporarylit.about.com/od/literaryterms/g/Narrative-Arc-What-Is-Narrative-Arc-In-Literature.htm)

> ***narrative arc** refers to the chronological construction of plot in a novel or story.*

It's probably being used somewhat loosely in OP's context to mean that the author has a consistent overall approach when writing about all nine parallel universes, and/or he's careful to ensure "seamless continuity" (using [segues](http://dictionary.reference.com/wordoftheday/archive/2002/11/15.html), perhaps) as he moves from writing about one to writing about the next.

To be honest, I don't think it would make much difference here if the word ***arc*** were to be simply omitted.

Comment: +1 In LitCrit and The Profession, the *arc* piece implies that the narrative has a certain degree of shapeliness - as Aristotle puts it, it is a "complete whole, having a beginning, a middle and an end".

Comment: @StoneyB: I must admit I don't remember it being used much, if at all, back in the 70s when I was doing LitCrit. And sure enough, NGrams suggests the popularity of the term has [skyrocketed in the past couple of decades](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=narrative+arc&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). I think our lecturers used to bang on more about the [overarching narrative](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22overarching+narrative%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).